# Multiple commits to neo4j from R

Tags: r, neo4j, r-neo4j

I have collected some tweets using the `twitteR` package and thereafter exported them to a neo4j database using Nicole White's various tutorials. I extract the tweets to a dataframe called `kdf` and thereafter use functions from `stringr` for basic cleaning up as demonstrated by Nicole. I am then sending this to neo4j from R. The essential part of my code is:

```
library(RNeo4j)
graph = startGraph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/", username="xxxx", password="xxxx")
clear(graph)

addConstraint(graph, "Tweet", "id")
addConstraint(graph, "User", "username")
addConstraint(graph, "Hashtag", "hashtag")
addConstraint(graph, "Tags", "ent_tag")


query = "
CREATE (tweet:Tweet {id: {tweetID}})
SET tweet.text = {text}

CREATE (user:User {name: {Username}})

CREATE (user)-[:TWEETED]->(tweet)
FOREACH(reply_to_sn IN CASE {reply_to_sn} WHEN NULL then [] else [{reply_to_sn}] END | 
MERGE (replytouser:User {username:{reply_to_sn}})
CREATE (tweet)-[:IN_REPLY_TO]->(replytouser)
)

FOREACH(retweet_sn IN CASE {retweet_sn} WHEN NULL THEN [] ELSE [{retweet_sn}] END |
MERGE(retweet_user:User {username: {retweet_sn}})
CREATE (tweet)-[:RETWEET_OF]->(retweet_user)
)

FOREACH(hastag_nodes IN CASE {hashtag_nodes} WHEN NULL then [] else [{hashtag_nodes}] END |
MERGE (h:Hashtag {hashtag :{hashtag_nodes}})
CREATE (tweet)-[:HASHTAG]->(h)
)

FOREACH(mentioned_users IN CASE {mentioned_users} WHEN NULL then [] else [{mentioned_users}] END |
MERGE (m:User {username :{mentioned_users}})
CREATE (tweet)-[:MENTIONED]->(m)
)

"
tx = newTransaction(graph)

for(i in 1:nrow(kdf)){
  row = kdf[i, ]
  appendCypher(tx, query,
               tweetID=row$id,
               text=row$text,
               Username=row$screenName,
               reply_to_sn=row$replyToSN,
               retweet_sn=getRetweetSN(row$text),
               hashtag_nodes=getHashtags(row$text),
               mentioned_users=getMentions(row$text))

}
commit(tx)
```

What I have done thereafter is extracted named entities for all the text using Watson's Alchemy API. This is stored in a dataframe called `ent_tbl`. This contains three variables, `tweetid`, `etext` and `etype`. Now I am trying to export this data too to the same neo4j databse and join on the id of the tweets. This is the other part of the code:

```
query="
MATCH(t:ent_tag {id : $twid, type :$etype, text :$etext}) 
MATCH(tw:tweet {tweetID : $twid }) 
CREATE (tw)-[:HAS_ENT]->(t) 
"
tx=newTransaction(graph)
for (i in 1:nrow(ent_tbl)){
  row = ent_tbl[i,]
  appendCypher(tx, query,
               twid=row2$tweetid,
               etype=row2$etype,
               etext=row2$etext)
}



commit(tx)
```

While I do not get any errors on committing this, `summary(graph)` does not show me the relationship between the tags (`t`) and the tweets (`tw`) that I expected to see.

```
> summary(graph)
   This          To    That
1  User     TWEETED   Tweet
2 Tweet  RETWEET_OF    User
3 Tweet     HASHTAG Hashtag
4 Tweet   MENTIONED    User
5 Tweet IN_REPLY_TO    User
```

Why would this happen? 
This is my db.schema in neo4j:

[image: db.schema]

Answer (score 2):

That is because the  `MATCH` does not find any tag or tweet so it breaks. If you want to add data to existing nodes, you should match them by ID and then set their properties. And you got to be consistent with labels and upper/lower cases. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
query="
MATCH(t:Tags {ent_tag : $twid}) 
MATCH(tw:Tweet {tweetID : $twid })
SET t.type=$etype, t.text=$etext
CREATE (tw)-[:HAS_ENT]->(t) 
"
tx=newTransaction(graph)
for (i in 1:nrow(ent_tbl)){
  row = ent_tbl[i,]
  appendCypher(tx, query,
           twid=row2$tweetid,
           etype=row2$etype,
           etext=row2$etext)
}



commit(tx)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tomaz, but the result is the same. No relationship.

Comment: i have changed the `MATCH (:Tags)` since i have noticed you used ent_tag to find the right tag

Comment: I am not sure if I follow entirely. What I have noticed is that the constraint on the Tags node is `CONSTRAINT ON ( tags:Tags ) ASSERT tags.ent_tag IS UNIQUE`

Comment: `:Tags` is a label of node while `ent_tag` is the unique property of the node, like a name of a person. When you are matching existing nodes, you should always match/merge by that unique property only and then set new properties and or create new relationships

Comment: Understood. But I am still not getting anywhere :) Should I try adding the second dataframe by converting it into a csv and then LOAD CSV?

Comment: No wouldnt solve anything... do the Tags you are matching exist already in the database or do you need to create them if not existent... it looks like it doesnt find them and so it breaks the query... in that case just change `MATCH(t:Tags {ent_tag : $twid})`  to `MERGE (t:Tags {ent_tag : $twid})`

Comment: Would it not require a `WITH` between `MERGE` and `MATCH`? I tried `MERGE` and added a `With t`. But the result was unfortunately the same.

Comment: Ok so if this doesnt work it means that the `MATCH` does not find your existing tweets... so that means something is wrong with you twittID param or something... Change that also to `MERGE` and it will work... and try to debug from results why does it not find existing tweets

Comment: Ok, will do. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One possibility is you saved your tweetID as an integer when first importing so `MATCH(tw:Tweet {tweetID : toINT($twid) })` might work...

Comment: I just checked, `str(kdf$id)` and `str(ent_tbl$tweetid)` are both characters. Guess I will convert them to numeric and then try.

Comment: Actually if you look at it the original code creates: (:Hashtag {hashtag:"text"}) that is what you have to match on.